# Is there a way of calculating the exponent x after a modulo?

Tags: algebra-precalculus, modular-arithmetic

Is it possible to calculate x, knowing all other parameters?

$y = b^x \pmod c$

My intention would be to do this with the logarithm but this brings up a new unkown parameter n:

$y+nc= b^x$

$x = \frac{\ln(y + nc)}{\ln(b)}$

So maybe there is another way of doing this in the world of modular arithmetic?

Comment: This is the notorious *discrete logarithm* problem.

Comment: This is the discrete logarithm problem, and it's so hard to solve that it is used in cryptography to encrypt files in a way that *computers* can't even crack efficiently (for large prime $c$).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The short answer is "there is no quick way".

A longer answer calls for much more number theory than is usually available at the algebra-precalculus level. First you have to figure out for which integers $c$ there is a $b$ for which there is always a solution $x$ for any $y$.

If $c$ is prime then there are values of $b$ that work, but finding them is pretty much trial and error. And once you have a good $b$, finding $x$ when you're told $y$ is also pretty much trial and error. In fact if you could find a fast way to do that you'd be on track to breaking some security measures. Several comments tell you this is the [discrete logarithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Discrete_logarithm) problem.

So if you have any particular examples you need to work out, all you can do is try all the values of $x$ modulo $c$ and see if you ever get $y$.